# C# Salesforce API Order and OrderItem creation

Tags: c#, api, soap, salesforce

Using C# and the Sales Force SOAP API I can successfully insert Order objects.

My question is, is it possible to create OrderItems along with the top-level Order properties?  I am currently running into Object reference errors when attempting to set the OrderItem attribute of the Orders object.

I know I could create an Order and then create OrderItems using its subsequent Id. But this seems a waste of API's.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I performed the operation in 3 stages.
 1) Add top level Order object
 2) Add OrderItems
 3) Activated Order.

I performed steps 1 & 2 using sObject[] array where possible to reduce API hits.